# SBT ResolveException for org.flywaydb#flyway-sbt;3.1

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, dependencies, sbt, flyway

I've been trying to use sbt for compiling the source code of a server app, written in scala. When I run the sbt script, it starts downloading some packages and resolving some dependencies and at the final step, it returns the following error:

```
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.flywaydb#flyway-sbt;3.1:not found
```

And if I ignore this error, I can't use commands like "compile", ...

I have compiled this source code before using sbt on ubuntu 14.04 and used the commands I needed, but now I'm running it on another system but on the same operating system and I am getting this error.

Is there anyway to resolve this dependency?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Show us your build.sbt

Comment: Looks like this is an sbt plugin. Did you had their `resolver` like they suggest here https://flywaydb.org/documentation/sbt ?

Comment: Looks like flyway repo is down or something. I am experiencing the same issues.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to switch your resolver from http to https and you should be good