# Flyway-sbt not Found

Tags: flyway

According to the Flywaydb [documentation provided](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/sbt/), I added Flyway to my `plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("org.flywaydb" % "flyway-sbt" % "4.0.3")
```

and to my resolvers in my main `build.sbt`:

```
resolvers += "Flyway" at "https://flywaydb.org/repo"
```

But upon build I'm getting the following:

```
[info] Resolving org.flywaydb#flyway-sbt;4.0.3 ...
[warn]  module not found: org.flywaydb#flyway-sbt;4.0.3
...
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.flywaydb#flyway-sbt;4.0.3: not found
```

I'm not sure why this is not resolving? According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35814062/sbt-resolveexception-for-org-flywaydbflyway-sbt3-1) it's an `https` issue, but I've made sure to indicate that here. Am I doing something wrong? If not, is there a way I can determine if that repository location is up, and if so if it has the requested module (`flyway-sbt` version 4.0.3)? I was unable to find documentation on this on Flyway's site.

The `flyway-core` for the same version can [be found here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.flywaydb/flyway-core/3.0), but no `sbt` plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `resolvers` must be updated inside the `plugins.sbt` file, not in the main `build.sbt` file. Doing this allows the dependency to be found and downloaded.